# Boise ID 6:55pm 2 lights in a row brighter than Jupiter -disappeared

Tags: jupiter

Ok there is another question like this from a month ago.  I am in Boise Idaho, and at 6:55 PM MST Nov 15, 2022, two lights brighter than Jupiter were about an inch to the north and east.  The two lights and Jupiter made almost a straight line.  I had enough time to pull out my star map to see if they were other planets- they were not. They then got brighter and then faded out.

Similar it sounds to another post from a month ago. Not Jupiter moons not Neptune which is to the west. Not satellites. No movement. What are possible explanations for these?

Comment: If astronomical, they were satellites. There most likely was motion but very small due to the range. If not astronomical, then you will not find the answer on Astronomy S.E.

Comment: Also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21960/two-lights-roughly-5-minutes-apart-about-as-bright-as-mars-or-maybe-saturn

Comment: If it happens again, check [flightradar24.com](https://www.flightradar24.com/) for an airplane flying toward you.

Comment: I added the date to your timestamp, is that correct? The aircraft headlight explanation seems viable, Boise Airport's runways run nortwest/southeast and Jupiter will be in the southeast

Comment: Hi there all thank you for the notes!  The two lights were not moving and we’re not planes.  Know the airport and the patterns well since I do work out there. Being a pilot I can assume you these were not planes flying at me which you are correct, in that they can look like a light staying still.  Total head scratcher.

Comment: Lights that appear and disappear are not likely to be astronomical in nature.  The identity of any such lights can be hard to determine if you were there, and even harder to determine from a description. But I am reasonably certain that whatever these were, they were terrestrial. I doubt a useful answer can be written, especially if you are certain that they are not planes.